# create online "diagnostic" questionnaire with results based on choices

Tags: webforms

Is this possible to achieve in drupal 7?
The example I found is here http://www.hairloss-research.com/alopecia-areata-diagnosis/

I tried to use webform module or quizz module but no luck. Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps: [Module for decision tree / guided entry](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2259/module-for-decision-tree-guided-entry). There is nothing which appears do the job out of the box. So you need to evaluate the modules if they full fill your needs. I am going to check following modules to build a so called decision tree:

- [Decision Tree](http://drupal.org/project/decision_tree)
- [D.A.I.L.](http://drupal.org/project/dail)
- Core Book
- [Outline Designer](http://drupal.org/project/outline_designer)
- [Choose Your Own Adventure](http://drupal.org/project/cyoa)
- [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select)
- [Conditional Fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields)
- ... to be continued ;)